What gesture is used to move in a 3D game on visionOS?
We can use keyboard's arrow keys to move any direction in immersive space while running on a visionOS simulator. But how can we achieve the same on real device?

Did I misunderstand your question? My answer would be simply "walk around".
If you want to simulate movement in the immersive space, without the wearer actually moving, you'll have to develop your own paradigm/vocabulary. Topo Maps+ solves this nicely by moving the device's viewpoint in the direction you're looking. A finger tap stops the movement and allows you to look around without repositioning the viewpoint.
Beware of inducing motion sickness in your users.

Hi @Hal Mueller: I'm not sure how feasible is the walk around if there are obstacles around user and if user enabled full immersive space. I'm looking for any gesture that can mimic this. Since I don't have device I'm not sure about it.

It's in general NOT feasible, for the reasons you stated.
If you're building something to, say, fly around the solar system, or walk through a 3D maze, or explore a generated landscape, then I think there's no standard gesture. You're free to develop your own...e.g. tap to stop/start. Or tap to move forward one "step".
Is there any way you can get time on a real device? Borrow from a friend? Visit an Apple Developer Lab? Buy and return in < 2 weeks? Developer kit loan from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/visionos/developer-kit/)? The real device is eye-opening (heh) compared to Sim.

Then I'm not sure how a user can move in a game scenario then? And wrt device loan, I'm not sure whether it is available for loan from Apple in my country (outside US).

Please add detail to your original question. And perhaps a screenshot, or a photo of a pencil/paper sketch.

Here is the video link - https://streamable.com/9ai1jh In this video you can see that I'm moving in all direction using Mac keyboard's direction keys.

Ah, now I see what you mean. I think you're going to have to choose your own convention for what gestures mean. Perhaps there are "standard" ideas on other VR platforms?  Take a look at documentation and WWDC 23 videos mentioning ARKit hand tracking, HandTrackingProvider, and SpatialTapGesture.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmY3zR5Z6G4 may be relevant, haven't watched it. You have an obviously polished project in the works, and I encourage you to apply for the Developer Kit loan I mentioned above.
